# Transferring minecraft pe worlds on an apple or iOS device

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

It was my birthday and I got a new iPhone. On my iPad I have awesome worlds in mc but I want them on my iPhone. How do I transfer worlds from one apple device to another???? :/

Comment: I'm not sure if this is possible on Apple devices.

Answer (score -1):

If this topic isn't dead yet, here are the steps to transfer your world without jailbreaking.

Minecraft PE does not save information on servers, it saves it on the device's local storage. If he was playing on an Android with removable storage, the transfer is as simple as using the old card in the new device.

If the old broken device can still open Minecraft then you can transfer the world by hosting a LAN game from it, joining it with the new device and hitting Quit and Copy World in the Pause menu.

If not, you'll have to transfer the data across using a USB cable via a computer. If the old device is broken to the point where this won't work, there's not much you can do I'm afraid.

Source: fredely

Comment: Wow, I take the time to write a new answer that complies with **your** terms and I still get a down vote? What do you expect me to do if his phone's broken? I'm not a wizard.